# Grep for range of numbers

Tags: grep, regular-expression

How would you search a log file for a date range?

Log file looks like this:

```
01/14 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
```

I need to condense the log to 10 minutes starting at 8:25 and going until 8:35

When I use the following egrep I find too many results, such as`00:08:25` `01:08:25` ... `08:25:00`..

How can I just get `08:25:00` through `08:35:59`

What I've tried

```
cat foo | egrep "08:2[5-9]|08:3[0-5]"
cat foo | egrep "08:2[5-9]:??|08:3[0-5]:??"
cat foo | egrep "08:2[5-9]:[0-9][0-9]|08:3[0-5]:[0-9][0-9]"
```

Comment: See if this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649387/extract-last-10-minutes-from-logfile/20649989#20649989

Comment: The answers there all strip out the log and just show the date. I need to preserve the log entries by filtering by date.

Comment: [How to grep a log file within a specific time period](http://superuser.com/questions/439688/how-to-grep-a-log-file-within-a-specific-time-period)

Comment: [Find entries in log file within timespan (eg. the last hour)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706095/find-entries-in-log-file-within-timespan-eg-the-last-hour)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should yield the desired result.

```
egrep "08:[2][5-9]:[0-5][0-9]|08:[3][0-5]:[0-5][0-9]" foo
```

Using `cat` in this case is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

With these inputs:

```
01/15 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 08:25:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 08:35:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
```

You can print all lines between two pattern, using `awk`:

```
awk -v date='01/14' '$1!=date{next};/08:25/,/08:35/' logfile

01/14 08:25:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 00:00:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
01/14 08:35:01  INFO:     received connect request from 10.10.10.10
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are open to use `sed`, you can do :

```
sed -n '/^01\/14 08:00/,/^01\/14 08:10/p' foo
```

In general, you can use bash variables replace with the specific times in the above command. For example:

```
st="01\/14 08:00"
en="01\/14 08:25"
sed -n "/^$st/,/^$en/p" foo #note the double quotes
```

You need to escape the `/` character with a `\` if using `/` as separator as shown in the above command.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder if this is a GNU sed specific syntax. I get error: 'invalid command code 1' when running on my mac (bsd sed)

Comment: This wouldn't really work if the log doesn't contain any entry with either `08:25` or `08:35`.

Comment: @devnull Thanks, I made a small edit in response.

Comment: @spuder I made an edit. Try again.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is still catching some incorrect values. `01/14 00:03:39  INFO:     job 11472436[14228] violates idle`

Comment: @spuder my bad, edited answer: test now.

Comment: It is also needed to sort the entries in case the range is not sequencial.

Answer (score 1):

You could use perl.  The following performs a lexical comparison on the time field which implies that it'd work even if you don't have a line containing the starting or ending time.

```
 yourprogram | perl -lane 'print if $F[1] ge "08:25:00" and $F[1] lt "08:36:00"'
```

This assumes that the time is the second field in your input and is of the form `hh:mm:ss`.

You could also specify the date by adding another condition:

```
 yourprogram | perl -lane 'print if $F[1] ge "08:25:00" and $F[1] lt "08:36:00" and $F[0] eq "01/14"'
```

---

The input is generated using the following script:

```
for ((h=8;h<9;h++)); do
  for ((m=20;m<40;m=m+2)); do
    for ((s=0;s<60;s=s+10)); do
      printf "01/14 %02d:%02d:%02d line %d\n" $h $m $s $((++l))
    done
  done
done
```

Executing

```
bash script | perl -lane 'print if $F[1] ge "08:25:00" and $F[1] lt "08:36:00"'
```

produces:

```
01/14 08:26:00 line 19
01/14 08:26:10 line 20
01/14 08:26:20 line 21
01/14 08:26:30 line 22
01/14 08:26:40 line 23
01/14 08:26:50 line 24
01/14 08:28:00 line 25
01/14 08:28:10 line 26
01/14 08:28:20 line 27
01/14 08:28:30 line 28
01/14 08:28:40 line 29
01/14 08:28:50 line 30
01/14 08:30:00 line 31
01/14 08:30:10 line 32
01/14 08:30:20 line 33
01/14 08:30:30 line 34
01/14 08:30:40 line 35
01/14 08:30:50 line 36
01/14 08:32:00 line 37
01/14 08:32:10 line 38
01/14 08:32:20 line 39
01/14 08:32:30 line 40
01/14 08:32:40 line 41
01/14 08:32:50 line 42
01/14 08:34:00 line 43
01/14 08:34:10 line 44
01/14 08:34:20 line 45
01/14 08:34:30 line 46
01/14 08:34:40 line 47
01/14 08:34:50 line 48
```