# grep multiple entries in openvpn.log

Tags: bash, sed, grep, openvpn

i need to determine which clients tried to connect to openvpn

```
$ grep -e 'client[1-20]' openvpn.log | sed 's/^.*client/client/'
```

gives me

```
client16
client16
client12_pool_defined = DISABLED
client12'/var/run/openvpn.pid'
client13
client15
client16
client16
```

any idea how to remove duplicate entries just leaving client12, client13 and so on?

Comment: Does adding `| uniq` give you the expected output or is further sorting needed?

Answer (score 1):

First: `grep 'client[1-20]'` does not look for `client` followed by numbers between 1 and 20. It looks for `client` followed by any character out of `0`, `1` and `2`. Using `grep` for a range of numbers is cumbersome and dealt with multiple times in this site. See, for example, [Grep for range of numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120831/70524), [Looking to grep or egrep year ranges from 1965-1996](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162348/70524), etc.

If you want just unique entries, use `sort -u` or `sort | uniq`.

Combined, something like (assuming zero-padded numbers):

```
grep -Eo 'client([01][1-9]|20)' | sort -u
```